# Field update after autocompletion with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm quite new to AngularJS and struggling a bit to have some input fields updated after an autocompletion event using google maps.
The idea is that when the user inputs his city/zip code, I would update 3 fields which are themselves linked to an object.
So far, I managed to have a working code except that sometimes the fields are not updated immediately : I have to autocomplete twice so that the good value will appear in the fields.
I've tweaked an existing angular directive in order to get what I want but since this is new to me, I dont know if I'm using the correct approach.

Below is the JS directive I use :

```
angular.module( "ngVilleAutocomplete", [])
 .directive('ngAutocomplete', function($parse) {
return {

  scope: {
    details: '=',
    ngAutocomplete: '=',
    options: '=',
    data: '='
  },

  link: function(scope, element, attrs, model) {

    //options for autocomplete
    var opts

    //convert options provided to opts
    var initOpts = function() {
      opts = {}
      if (scope.options) {
        if (scope.options.types) {
          opts.types = []
          opts.types.push(scope.options.types)
        }
        if (scope.options.bounds) {
          opts.bounds = scope.options.bounds
        }
        if (scope.options.country) {
          opts.componentRestrictions = {
            country: scope.options.country
          }
        }
      }
    }
    initOpts()

    //create new autocomplete
    //reinitializes on every change of the options provided
    var newAutocomplete = function() {
      scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], opts);
      google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            scope.details = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
            //console.log(scope.details)
            var HasCP = false;
            for (var i=0 ; i<scope.details.address_components.length ; i++){
              for (var j=0 ; j<scope.details.address_components[i].types.length ; j++){
                if (scope.details.address_components[i].types[j] == 'postal_code' && scope.data.CP != 'undefined'){
                  scope.data.CP = scope.details.address_components[i].long_name;
                  HasCP = true;
                } else if (scope.details.address_components[i].types[j] == 'locality' && scope.data.Ville != 'undefined') {
                  scope.data.Ville = scope.details.address_components[i].long_name;
                } else if (scope.details.address_components[i].types[j] == 'country' && scope.data.Pays != 'undefined') {
                  scope.data.Pays = scope.details.address_components[i].long_name;
                }
              }
            }
            if (!HasCP){
              var latlng = {lat: scope.details.geometry.location.lat(), lng: scope.details.geometry.location.lng()};
              var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

              geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  for (var i=0 ; i<results[0].address_components.length ; i++){
                      for (var j=0 ; j<results[0].address_components[i].types.length ; j++){
                        if (results[0].address_components[i].types[j] == 'postal_code' && scope.data.CP != 'undefined'){
                          scope.data.CP = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
                          console.log('pc trouvé :' + scope.data.CP);
                        } 
                      }
                  }
                }
              });

            }

            //console.log(scope.data)
            scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
        });
      })
    }
    newAutocomplete()

    //watch options provided to directive
    scope.watchOptions = function () {
      return scope.options
    };
    scope.$watch(scope.watchOptions, function () {
      initOpts()
      newAutocomplete()
      element[0].value = '';
      scope.ngAutocomplete = element.val();
    }, true);
  }
};
```

});

The matching HTML code is below :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <lable>Code postal : </label>
                    <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="cities_autocomplete" details="cities_autocomplete_details" options="cities_autocomplete_options" data="client" placeholder="Code postal" ng-model="client.CP" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lable>Ville : </label>
                     <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete="cities_autocomplete" details="cities_autocomplete_details" options="cities_autocomplete_options" data="client" placeholder="Ville" ng-model="client.Ville" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <lable>Pays : </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Pays" ng-model="client.Pays" placeholder="Pays" />
                </div>
```

You'll see that I pass the "client" object directly to my directive which then updates this object. I expected angular to update the html page as soon as the values of the client object are updated but I will not always be the case :

1. If I search twice the same city, the values are not updated
2. If I search a city, Google wont send me a zip code so I have to do another request to the geocoding service and I get the zipcode in return but while my client.CP field is correctly updated, changes are not visible in the CP input field until I do another search.

Thanks in advance for any advice on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Just a fast comment, you should not use the 'ng' before your module and your directive as it is reserved for angular directives. You should rename them to mach the firsts letter of your actuel project name :). Could you provide a plunker showing your issue ? It would be helping a lot to help you getting out of your bug.

Comment: Here's a plunker, feel free to test  : [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/cO4bqXoPD5nbLWRdVm3x?p=preview